# Changing class without changing a schema

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a xsd schema which I'm not allowed to change. It produce generated java classes.

Assume that classes looks as follows:

```
       class Data {
          protected List<Value> value;
          ... 
       }
       class Value {
           ...
        }
```

Now I need to have my own MyValue ideally to be extended from Value.

```
class MyValue extends Value {

     Integer myOwnField1;
     Long anotherProperty;

}
```

And be able to say unmarshaller to use MyValue instead of Value when it parses xml file.

Later I would be able to use the fact that MyValue can contain some useful new fields inside, make operations over them, change them, etc. So I want extend the functionality which I have in schema without changing it.

Is that somehow possible to replace Value by MyValue for unmarshaller?

Apart from the obvious way to create a Map where I can map object which was generated by unmarshaller with my own fields and properties in MyValue. I'd like to avoid this way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you load the list using bean properties?

```
public void setValue(List<Value> value) {
    this.value = ...convert to List<MyValue>...
}
```

Comment: `Data` class is generated from XSD. Her point is to use children of this class without modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [unmarshalling by declared type](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalByDeclaredType): indeed, if you override your XSD from the root element to every child element you need to override, you could use a second argument in `unmarshal` method to sepecify your custom mapping.

```
<T> JAXBElement<T> unmarshal(Source source,
                             Class<T> declaredType)
                         throws JAXBException
```

> [...] declaredType - appropriate JAXB mapped class to hold
>   source's xml root element

(see [Unmarshaller javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20java.lang.Class%29) for more detailed info)